# Keeping Integrate from making unnecessary assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I would like to evaluate the integral
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x \, \exp\left(- a x^2 - x^4\right)$ for any real value of $a$. *Mathematica* 8.0.4 gives the following result:

```
Integrate[Exp[- a x^2  - x^4], {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {a ∈ Reals}]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[1/2 Sqrt[a] E^(a^2/8) BesselK[1/4, a^2/8], a >= 0]
> ```

Can I keep *Mathematica* from restricting its answer to non-negative values of $a$, especially since it can do the integral also for negative values:

```
Integrate[Exp[- a x^2  - x^4], {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {a < 0}]
```

> ```
> (Sqrt[-a] E^(a^2/8) π (BesselI[-(1/4), a^2/8] + BesselI[1/4, a^2/8]))/(2 Sqrt[2])
> ```

I can construct the solution for all real $a$ from these two restricted solutions using `Piecewise`, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: Not a real solution, but *if you know that conditions aren't needed*, you could cheat by adding the option `GenerateConditions -> False` to `Integrate`. Then `Assumptions -> {a ∈ Reals}` is sufficient.

Comment: That's good to know. Unfortunately, in this case, the condition is needed, as otherwise Mathematica returns only the solution for a>0. I don't mind (not that it would matter if I did!) that there are two separate expressions for the value of the integral for a>0 and for a<0, I just wish that Mathematica could automatically give the combined piecewise result, rather than arbitrarily choosing only the a>0 solution.

Comment: Even more troublesome is the situation where the solution is actually valid for all _a_ on the real line, but mma still returns `ConditionalExpression[sol, a > 0]`

Comment: If you accept to be pragmatic, maybe define `int[a_] = 
 UnitStep[a] Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 - x^4], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {a >= 0}] + 
  UnitStep[-a] Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 - x^4], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {a < 0}]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a system option, `ConditionalAnswerFormat`, which controls how conditional results are output. First here's a function to evaluate an expression with a temporarily different setting for `ConditionalAnswerFormat`:

```
SetAttributes[withCAF, HoldFirst];
withCAF[expr_, caf_] :=
 Module[{originalCAF, result},
  originalCAF = SystemOptions[ConditionalAnswerFormat];
  SetSystemOptions[ConditionalAnswerFormat -> caf];
  result = expr;
  SetSystemOptions[originalCAF];
  result]
```

If you use `If` as the setting, *Mathematica* will output conditional results in an `If` statement (I think this is what used to happen before version 8):

```
Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 - x^4], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals}] ~withCAF~ If
```

[image]

As pointed out in the question, *Mathematica* can actually do the unevaluated integral. You can just copy and paste it into an input cell and get a result:

```
Integrate[E^(-x^2 (a + x^2)), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals && a < 0]
```

[image]

Of course the integral didn't get evaluated inside the `If` statement because `If` has the `HoldRest` attribute. So what if we use a setting for `ConditionalAnswerFormat` which evaluates the results *before* feeding them to `If`, and then applies a `PiecewiseExpand`. This can be done easily with a `Composition`:

```
Integrate[Exp[-a x^2 - x^4], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals}] ~withCAF~ Composition[PiecewiseExpand, If]
```

[image]

Comment: The value of the integral should be `1/2 Gamma[1/4]` at zero, but I don't think your final result gives that. I think it's indeterminate at zero.

Comment: @m_goldberg That's also an issue with the original `ConditionalExpression` result. You can use `Limit` to get the correct result at a=0.

Comment: I did use `Limit`; that's how I know what the value of zero should be.